# Как запретить выполнение функции JQuery на указанное время?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код для смены класса:

```
$(function() {
    $("#drop").click(function() {       
        $("#plus").toggleClass("round-405");
    })
});
```

Он выполняется при нажатии на кнопку выпадающего меню (bootstrap).
Проблема заключается в том, что выпадение меню происходит дольше и его нельзя отменить. И если в момент выпадения кликнуть по кнопке еще раз, то опять сработает функция и изменится класс без изменения меню.
Как можно сделать задержку между срабатыванием этой функции, не влезая в bootstrap.js?

Разметка:

```
<a id="drop" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <span class="menu-title">Показать категории</span>
    <span class="category-icon"><i id="plus"class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</a>
```

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _не влезая в bootstrap.js_?

Comment: Имею в виду изменить конкретно этот код, без синхронизации с функцией bootstrap'a, чтобы туда не влезать и не ковыряться там. Хотелось бы сделать ограничение во времени на повторное выполнение функции.

Comment: что за функция бутстрапа? и как ты хочешь синхронизироваться с ней, не синхронизируясь?

Comment: В файле bootstrap.min.js. Там выполняется код выпадающего меню.

Comment: Хочу не синхронизируясь, чтобы в той каше не ковыряться.

Comment: как это все связывается с разметкой? добавь html

Comment: добавь этот пример и пример списка в сам вопрос

Comment: Добавил разметку  в вопрос.

Comment: вообще тут яваскрипт код вообще не нужен: вместо отдельного класса _round-405_ можно использовать настройку стиля для #plus, в зависимости от того, какое значение атрибута `aria-expanded` у контейнера

Comment: бутстрап при клике меняет этот атрибут, браузер сам перерисует в соответствии с css, при повторном клике, соответственно обратно

Comment: хотя в принципе и сейчас проблемы быть не должно. можешь сделать [mcve], в котором проблема _если в момент выпадения кликнуть по кнопке еще раз, то опять сработает функция и изменится класс без изменения меню._ воспроизводится?

Comment: А как тогда динамически изменить #plus при нажатии на ссылку и обратно?

Comment: ничего не надо менять. нужно в определении css где сейчас стоит _round-405_ поставить `[aria-expanded=true] #plus`

Comment: что за класс `round-405`?

Comment: .round-405 { rotate(405deg) }

Comment: замени это на `[aria-expanded=true] #plus { rotate(405deg) }`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Даже не знал такого селектора. Все работает и без скрипта.